# PHP - using global vs passing by reference

Tags: php, variables, reference, global

Is there any practical difference between using globals and passing param by reference?

Simple example:

```
$my_var = 5;
$my_var2 = 3;

function add_one(&$i){
    return $i++;
}

function add_one_global(){
    global $my_var2;
    return $my_var2++;
}    

add_one($my_var);
echo "$my_var<br>";

add_one_global();
echo "$my_var2";
```

The output is:

```
6
4
```

Both of them modify global variable (**aware that it should be avoided if possible**), "add_one" seems to be a little bit more flexible, but apart from that is there any other difference?

Comment: Using the global keyword is bad practice

Comment: Why to use the global variables at all, why not pass values by function arguments and return them with `return`?

Comment: Yes, I know that it shouldn't be done (even bolded it in my question). I'm simply curious what's the difference (if any) between those two.

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with using them if the situation really needs them. This question is opinion based, and you will get extremes, and no solid answers.

Comment: Example of a difference when using them: It's usually much harder to write tests with mock-objects for specific functions if you're using globals. With "pass-by-reference", the function will simply use what it's given, which can change for each call.

Comment: When debuggin its much harder to keep track of a global variable.  It's hard to tell where, when and how many times the data has changed.  If you're dealing with a class property ( for example ) it's much easier to keep track, because the scope is limited to just the class.

Comment: pass by reference is a whole other deal then the scope of a variable.  Object are always passed by reference.  It can also be useful if your modifying something and don't want to create an extra copy, such as sorting an array.  Could you return the sorted array, sure, but then you are making a copy of it.  Pass by reference can get messy, debugging wise, because it may not be clear how something changed from one scope to the next.  For example, if you pass a variable to a class, and change it by reference, it may not be clear from the outside that it was modified.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, there is no difference. What kind of difference did you expect? The only real difference is the one that you noticed yourself - the pass-by-reference is more flexible and doesn't pollute the global namespace.

If this is for a small one-off script that you need to run once and then discard, go for whichever is fastest for you.

If this is for something that will keep working for a while, pick the pass-by-reference. It will be a lot easier down the road when you need to do some modifications to the script (and that's a **when**, not an **if**).